# How do i store bluetooth input data received from Arduino in a array?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Arduino sends data from a sensor via bluetooth. I want to store the data in a array to operate with them.

This part obtains the data from the characteristic

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        Log.v("AndroidLE", "broadcastUpdate()");
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        //Log.v("AndroidLE", "data.length: " + data.length);

        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
              for(byte byteChar : data) {
                  stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                //Log.v("AndroidLE", String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            }

            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            Log.v("AndroidLE", new String(data));
            Log.v("AndroidLE", stringBuilder.toString());
            //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data));
            //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, stringBuilder.toString());
        }

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

the data has these formats in logcat

```
2020-10-18 14:27:07.434 32292-32292 V/AndroidLE: 415
    419
    418
    418
    
    34 31 35 0D 0A 34 31 39 0D 0A 34 31 38 0D 0A 34 31 38 0D 0A 
2020-10-18 14:27:07.446 32292-32339 V/AndroidLE: broadcastUpdate()
2020-10-18 14:27:07.448 32292-32339 V/AndroidLE: 417
    417
2020-10-18 14:27:07.449 32292-32339 V/AndroidLE: 34 31 37 0D 0A 34 31 37
```

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                updateConnectionState(true);
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                updateConnectionState(false);
                clearUI();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                connect_caracterist_ard(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
               **storage_vect(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));**
            }
        }
    };
```

Any idea how to perform this function?

Maybe i should start by modifying the format in the broadcastUpdate, but I don't understand that well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already receive your data as Bytearry, but your code takes each byte, converts it to the corresponding Hex value and stores the result in a string.

Modify your `broadcastUpdate` to this:

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, data);
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

This gets rid of the Stringbuilder and only adds the raw data to the Intent. If you receive data from multiple different characteristics you should also add `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CHAR, characteristic.getUuid().toString());`. This enables you to handle data from other characteristics differently.

You can receive the data in your `onReceive` function by calling `intent.getByteArrayExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA)`